# Serving excel sheet (.xls) to browser for download using rails & angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I am using spreadsheet gem to generate .xls file. After writing it to a file, I am trying to send to client browser for download.

Below is the code in rails

```
workbook = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
# Constructed the data
file = "/path/to/file/sheet.xls"
workbook.write file
send_file file
```

This file when opened contains expected data in ideal format.

Below is the code in js:

```
CustomRestService.custom_post("report",{report_data: angular.toJson($scope.report_data)},"download_xls",{}).then (data)->
    if data
      hiddenElement = document.createElement('a')
      angular.element(document.body).append(hiddenElement)
      hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/xls,' + encodeURI(data)
      hiddenElement.target = '_blank'
      hiddenElement.download = "report.xls"
      hiddenElement.click()
      hiddenElement.remove()
```

But the file getting downloaded in browser contains junk data. I tried multiple solutions like below:

1. Using send_data, instead of send_file
2. Generated xls data and wrote to StringIO object to directly download
3. Constructed Blob object in js, with type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" and trying to download it.

All attempts failed, as I am missing something. All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "/path/to/file/sheet.xls"
tempfile = Tempfile.new(filename)
workbook = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
...
workbook.write(tempfile.path)
send_file tempfile.path, :filename => filename
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43297411/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply.